# Get Insagram photos from an open profile without making user login

Tags: api, profile, instagram

Is there a way to get public photos from Instagram without making the user login? There must be, but I cant find any way...

Comment: What kind of photos do you want to retrieve? Photos by a person? By tag? Location?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the photo of a specific user, you need to authenticate the user and use this endpoint:

```
/users/USER_ID/media/recent
```

Other endpoints that are not user-specific require only a client_id and no access token. For example:

```
/media/popular
/tags/TAG_ID/media/recent/
/locations/LOCATION_ID/media/recent
```

Comment: Is there a specific endpoint-call so I can show the number of followers?

Comment: /users/USER_ID provides the follower count.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[USER ID]/media/recent/?client_id=[CLIENT ID]`

[CLIENT ID] would be valid client id registered in app through manage clients (not related to user).
If you do not have user id get it from username by performing GET users search request:
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&client_id=[CLIENT ID]`